# JB Kwikwood to fill in old screw holes

Tags: wood

I am repairing a guard rail for a deck, can Kwikwood putty be counted on after filling in the old screw hole to hold the new screw safely?

Comment: The package says it will work, but I would pre-drill the fully set repair with the proper sized drill before installing the screw.  Wood flexes and fibers open up to accept a screw, but I doubt this material would.

Comment: The answer has more to do with the condition of the wood to which the epoxy bonds. It's up to you to clean out the hole and remove damaged, rotted, or loose wood.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manufacturer's web site](https://www.jbweld.com/products/kwikwood-epoxy-putty-1oz), it should be strong enough. But personally, I would be wary and, if possible without too much trouble, I would either add an additional screw (and bracket, etc. if needed) a few inches away or move the existing screw (and bracket, etc.) a few inches away from the original screw location.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question. However...

I'd recommend drilling out the hole where the old screw went, gluing in a replacement dowel (use a waterproof glue or epoxy), then drive the screw into the replacement wood.

For something like a railing, the stronger the better, and a screw will hold much better in wood than epoxy.